# Stop cl.exe from outputting source filename

Tags: visual-c++

Is there a way to tell cl.exe to not print out the name of the source file? Basically, I want it to output nothing when a file compiles cleanly. In a sane world, the compiler would send error messages to stderr and I could just redirect stdout to null. But for some reason cl.exe like to send compilation errors to stdout, which makes it hard to tell whether it had succeeded or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether a progam succeeded, don't look at its output, check the `%ERRORLEVEL%`.